# Do I need to put copper pieces on the eyes to cast the Gentle Repose spell if I have a spellcasting focus?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spell-components

The material components of the [*gentle repose*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/gentle-repose) spell are:

> a pinch of salt and one copper piece placed on each of the corpse's eyes, which must remain there for the duration

The rules for [material components](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#MaterialM) (PHB p. 203) state:

> A character can use a **component pouch** or **spellcasting focus** in place of the components specified for a spell. But if a cost is indicated for a component, a character must have that specific component before he or she can cast the spell.
>
> If a spell states that a material component is consumed by the spell, the caster must provide this component for each casting of the spell.

The material component is not explicitly consumed by *gentle repose*, although the spell does specify with unusual detail how the components are to be used and how the components must remain with the body for the spell to function. **This is different to the normal scenario where you just wave the component about then put it back into your pocket.** The component is expected to actually do something.

While the material component is a thing with monetary value (because it is money), it does not explicitly specify a cost. Based on [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/122661/48827) on *detect thoughts* (which also has a copper piece as a material component), **I assume that the copper pieces do not count as having an indicated 'cost'** for the purposes of being a material component.

If I have a spellcasting focus I can use, can I avoid the need to place copper pieces on each of the corpse's eyes? Or must I still put copper pieces on the eyes even if I have a spellcasting focus?

---

Due to repeated confusion, I thought I would say this outright. This question is not a duplicate of [Do I need to hold an actual copper piece in order to cast Detect Thoughts?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/122661/48827) That question was concerned with the *value* of the copper pieces. However, this question is concerned with what you must *do* with the copper pieces. *Detect thoughts* does not specify what must be done with the copper pieces. *Gentle repose* specifies that something specific must be done with the copper pieces for the spell to work. Does the clause on what must be done with the material component, irrespective of its cost, void your ability to use a spellcasting focus?

Comment: Related: [Do the eyes need to be in the corpse for Gentle Repose to work?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/139939/35259)

Comment: Very related, possible duplicate: [Can a focus replace a material component if it doesn't state a value in the component list?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/138808/can-a-focus-replace-a-material-component-if-it-doesnt-state-a-value-in-the-comp) (it mentions *detect thoughts* which also requires "a copper piece"), and even more specifically, [Do I need to hold an actual copper piece in order to cast Detect Thoughts?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/122661/do-i-need-to-hold-an-actual-copper-piece-in-order-to-cast-detect-thoughts)

Comment: @V2Blast Whether those are duplicates or not I'd say comes down to whether they address the part of this question that says "_This is different to the normal scenario where you just wave the component about then put it back into your pocket._", which I see as the major way in which this question differs from just "_Does a copper piece count as having value for the purposes of using a focus instead?_" (which is what I believe those other questions approximate to).

Comment: Related: [To cast Find the Path, can a caster substitute an object from the location they wish to find with a component pouch?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/103681/48827)
It's not quite the same, since *find the path*'s component relies on uniqueness while *gentle repose* specifies a use of a common component.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## There is [no flavor text](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/78022/59609) in D&D 5e Spells.

If the text says you have to do certain things, you have to do them. The text says to put the coins there, so you have to.

You can use a component pouch or spellcasting focus in place of the coins, as per the Material rules, if you prefer. But either way it has to be done in order for the spell to function.

Comment: When writing this question I entertained the mental picture of laying your wand or staff on the corpse's eyes when casting *gentle repose* and leaving the wand/staff/other focus there - which is clearly not economical but definitely amusing. I am glad other people have also thought of that.

Comment: @BBeast I can imagine an impatient wizard pulling out their entire sack of components, "I'm sure there's some salt and coins in there somewhere" and throwing it onto the corpses face.

Answer (score 1):

To me, two copper pieces is a stated cost, so personally I require the caster to actually use two copper pieces and put (and keep) them on the eyes.