# Can Glyph of Warding be used with Gentle Repose?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spell-components

The spell [Glyph of Warding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/glyph-of-warding) allows one to charge the glyph with a spell that is cast when the glyph is triggered:

> **Spell Glyph**. You can store a prepared spell of 3rd level or lower in the glyph by casting it as part of creating the glyph. The spell must target a single creature or an area. The spell being stored has no immediate effect when cast in this way. When the glyph is triggered, the stored spell is cast. If the spell has a target, it targets the creature that triggered the glyph. If the spell affects an area, the area is centered on that creature. If the spell summons hostile creatures or creates harmful objects or traps, they appear as close as possible to the intruder and attack it. If the spell requires concentration, it lasts until the end of its full duration.

The spell [Gentle Repose](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/gentle-repose) preserves a corpse from being raised by the dead and extends the amount of time spells like Raise Dead and Revivify have to operate on it. However, the material requirements of the spell are:

> a pinch of salt and one copper piece placed on each of the corpse's eyes, which must remain there for the duration

Further, [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/159067/73324) suggests that placing the coins is not an optional step in casting the spell.

In theory, the Glyph of Warding spell would seem to allow a Cleric to place the Gentle Repose spell in the glyph, with the trigger that it activate when someone nearby dies. However, given that when the glyph activates there may not be anyone present to place the coins on the corpse's eyes, is this spell (and any spell that requires the caster to perform some additional action) essentially incompatible with Glyph of Warding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that the glyph "must target a single creature or an area" prevents it from working here:

> You touch a *corpse or other remains*. For the duration, the target is protected from decay and can't become undead.

A corpse is not an area or creature. While there is some debate at [Is a dead creature's body considered an "object"?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/55951/42375), reading the text of Glyph of Warding makes it clear that the spell is activated when something living, animated at least, does the right thing (or wrong thing). For example, the text calls out "the intruder".

Answer (score -2):

This may sound a little weird, but the storing of the spell would store the material components, so the coins would be stored as well. the glyph then carries out the actions that happen in the spell, which includes placing said coins on the eyes. It isn't a 100% cut and dry RAW, but it seems well withing RAI.