# What level of knowledge constitutes being familiar with a location for clerics casting Find the Path?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, divination

In the answer [to this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/103681/to-cast-find-the-path-can-a-caster-substitute-an-object-from-the-location-they) it is determined that, RAW, a cleric only needs the 100gp of divinatory tools and a component pouch to cast *Find the Path*.

The text to *Find the Path* includes

> This spell allows you to find the shortest, most direct physical route to a specific fixed location that you are familiar with on the same plane of existence.

Using the RAW answer linked above, how does a Cleric become familiar with a location? Do they have to visit it? Hear about it? See it in a divinely-inspired vision? See it through a magic mirror, or a mundane spyglass? How do we define being familiar with something and where exactly is the line where something becomes familiar?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### It's up to the DM, but the *teleport* spell gives some insight.

Unfortunately, "familiar with" is given no clear or objective definition in the rules. However, the *teleport* spell gives some insight, as familiarity plays a role in that spell's success:

> "Very familiar" is a place you have been very often, a place you have carefully studied, or a place you can see when you cast the spell. "Seen casually" is someplace you have seen more than once but with which you aren't very familiar. "Viewed once" is a place you have seen once, possibly using magic. "Description" is a place whose location and appearance you know through someone else's description, perhaps from a map.

Obviously, the "very familiar" category as described here qualifies for *find the path*, and "seen casually" seems to qualify as well - "not very familiar" still implies *some* level of familiarity.

"Viewed once" is the tough one. I have had my players use *scrying* to spy on an NPC, and then try to use *find the path* to get there. On one occasion, they *recognized* the location, and though they had never been there and only seen it through *scrying*, they were aware of the rough geographical location, so I let them use *find the path*. They tried this another time, and had no idea where the location seen through *scrying* was, so I did not allow them to use *find the path*.

Comment: Fleshed out with experience as DM, and rulings, to 'show not tell' - like this answer, and I'll use this as a DM.